# How to build Installers for java7

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I have Netbeans Platform Application project. I have to build installers for all supported platforms, with using nbi. It should be built on Java8 and works on Java7.
my error is, when I try to install my application to machine with only java7

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/apple/eawt/ApplicationListener : 
Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I figured out that nbi.engine should rebuild with javac.target=1.7 but netbeans does not contain that sources.
Can you help me, how to download nbi.engine sources?

Comment: contact Apple... Or use another installer builder.

Comment: I'm using nbi on macos which is by default, how I can use another builder, and which ?